# Android apk crashes after setting MinifyEnabled true

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I receive following error when I follow Device Monitor :

```
Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
```

If I set minifyEnabled as false and use zipalign + redex to publish apk everything works well.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding project also tried adding following lines into proguard file :

```
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *;
```

And build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.evinsahibi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-           core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
   }
```

Comment: min sdk version was higher than the libraries..so check once

Comment: @sasikumar how it works on debug mode ? Also I want to support 5.0 devices minimum. Which libraries are incompatible  ? Thanks.